Why my API given Forbidden error to ADMIN role user
I created a api in springBoot, with mapping /admin/getAllUsers that have defined role of ADMIN. So, when user(have ADMIN role) try to access this api, it is giving forbidden error. I am attaching screenshots of code. please refer.
security Config class
define /admin/getAllUsers api
Below is users entity code
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Users implements UserDetails{
    
    @Id
    private ObjectId userid;
    @Indexed
    @NonNull
    private String userName;
    @NonNull
    private String password;
    @DBRef
    private List<JournalEntry> journalEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private List<String> roles;
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}

user profile
postman API error image
please check. it will really help me to understand this concept.
I tried to provide ADMIN role to api and try to access the all registered users. but it is giving forbidden error.
I am expecting that it will correctly return all registered users i.e., present in my mongo collection.

Are you getting exception only for this api, or all api ?

Dont post images as code as it is against the rules extract the code and edit your question to include it well formatted.
